# Trying to use while loop in java to keep asking user for input

Tags: java

I am working on a java code and I want to keep asking the user for input until he chooses to end using while loop and I have tried many different things but all I am getting is errors.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test42 {
    static int power(int x, int y) {
        if (y == 0)
            return 1;
        else if (y % 2 == 0)
            return power(x, y / 2) * power(x, y / 2);
        else
            return x * power(x, y / 2) * power(x, y / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner adnan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value of X:");
        int x = adnan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of Y:");
        int y = adnan.nextInt();
   
        System.out.println("The result is: " + power(x, y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made the method power as a static method. Thus, you should call the method by the class name.

You should invoke the method like this:

```
System.out.println("The result is: " + Test42.power(x, y));
```

And then it will work.

Comment: I guess you did not get my question my code is working perfectly fine but I need to make the user able to keep on giving input and getting output until the user chooses to stop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue the program to run until user chooses not to proceed then use `do-while` and ask for user input whether to proceed further or not.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

  static int power(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0)
      return 1;
    else if (y % 2 == 0)
      return power(x, y / 2) * power(x, y / 2);
    else
      return x * power(x, y / 2) * power(x, y / 2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner adnan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cont = "N";
    do {
      System.out.print("Enter the value of X:");
      int x = adnan.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter the value of Y:");
      int y = adnan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("The result is: " + power(x, y));
      System.out.print("Do you want to continue [Y/N]:");
      cont = adnan.next();
    } while (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
  }
}
```